# Where should validation occur: endpoint or object?

Tags: oop, api, validation, design-patterns

I know this has been asked more generally before, but here is my specific situation:

I have an endpoint (API exposed to clients/users) that ends up calling public member functions of some objects. Should I validate at the endpoint or at the member function?

It seems that validating at the endpoint is a little easier in this case because then all of my validation is done around my API functions.

But somehow it feels like the objects should maintain themselves and prevent invalid data from being used on their own functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation can be, and usually is, quite complex process, that involves lots of heavy, bussiness-related logic and which has plenty of dependencies to the outer resources.

I suppose it's better to let the client create invalid object and validate it at the very end - just before its use in the bussines service.